# Configuring a migrated Rails app - how to convince Apache to point to my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

How do I get Apache to point to the Rails app? I have my Rails app in /var/www and I successfully installed Passenger, Ruby, Rails, MySQL. This is a new server and I'm just trying to move an existing production Rails app to it. I thought it might be something in httpd.conf but there's no reference to the app in the running server's conf.

### Update

I already had my httpd.conf updated with the Passenger lines:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Also, I have a vhosts file which is identical to the original:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@ourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/tutorials/public
   ServerName tutorials.ourdomain.local
   ErrorLog logs/tutorials_error.log
   CustomLog logs/tutorials_access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

### Update 2

I found that I can stop serving the default Apache page by commenting out all lines of welcome.conf. Now I get the 403 forbidden page "you don't have permission to access / on this server" Even though I chmod 777'd the app directory and its contents (and /var/www).

### Update 3

I found I can access the default Rails page by going to [ipaddress]/findex.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinux was the culprit. Setenforce 0, service httpd restart proved this fact.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit your Apache configuration file like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /somewhere/passenger-x.x.x/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
PassengerRoot /somewhere/passenger/x.x.x
PassengerMaxPoolSize 10


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myapp.com
    DocumentRoot /www/myapp/public
    <Directory /www/myapp/public>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

More on the [Phusion Passenger users guide for Apache](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html).

Comment: What you see pointing your borwser to tutorials.ourdomain.local? Does your request appear in your access log?

Comment: OK, I looked at the default apache page and saw that I have to edit welcome.conf to not show the default. I commented all the lines and now I have 403 forbidden page, "you don't have permission to access / on this server." I chmod 777 the app directory and its contents and still have the 403.

Comment: Looks like Passenger / Rails are not even already involved. Have you (bless me for this question) copied all the file contained in the original installation? If you put a static HTML file in the public folder, is it served from Apache?

Comment: I tar'd the original app directory and untarr'd in into a directory I made in /var/www so that it appears as the original. I put a static index.htm page into /var/www and var/www/html and they are not served. I'm able to access the functioning app by typing the ip address into my browser. With the new one, I get the 403 fail by typing the ip address. With the static index.htm, I get 403 still and when I type [ip]/index.htm.

Comment: I just notice you said "public" folder. I hadn't checked there. I looked and saw findex.html was already in there so I went to [ip]/findex.html and wala, there's the rails default page! We're going in the right direction I think.